# Raid Mirror with 2 USB hard drives

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, raid, nas

Is there a way to setup raid mirror with 2 identical USB attached hard drives?

Not by using rsync or something...

The thing is I want NAS solution, but I don't want to buy expensive NAS and I already have mini PC which I use to stream movies (I don't need hard drives during that time, only system ssd)

And I want full data redundancy...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a raid1 using the standard tool for software raid in Linux: mdraid / mdadm

Some caveats apply wrt using USB:
https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/What%27s_all_this_with_USB%3F

Comment: Thanks, I'll post results, once I catch time to test it.

Comment: you are welcome, maybe you want to vote on my answer? :-)

Comment: Not until I confirm it works, then maybe I'll down-vote it :D